# enable pushbutton after some line edit have been filled

Tags: macos, qt

How to activate a push button in qt after some qlineedit have been filled? So the button should become enabled after some line edit have been modified

Comment: Connect the `textChanged()` Signal to a Slot in which you check if there is text in the input. Enable/Disable the button based on that

Comment: but it is not one aline edit, there are some of them

Comment: @programingdelphi, handle signals from all of them and check the content. If all line edits contain what you need, enable/disable the button.

Comment: how to handle signals from all of them? can you help please

Comment: Just connect these signales from all lineedits to one slot in which you then check them all for content

Comment: any line of code because I am new and I don't know where to begin with

Comment: [I suggest you read this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/signalsandslots.html)

Comment: connect(ui->lineEdit,SIGNAL(textChanged()),ui->pushButton,SLOT(setEnabled(true)));//this is not working . why?

Comment: QObject::connect: No such slot QPushButton::setEnabled(true)//this is the error

Comment: You cant pass parameter values in `QObject::connect`. It asks for types. Even if it worked, it would not be a solution. Store your line edits in a container, like `QList`. Connect `QLineEdit::textChanged` signals to your own custom slot. In this slot, iterate through the `QLineEdit`s in your `QList` and check if they all contain some text. If they do, enable your button. If they don't, disable your button.

Comment: In fact I want just to enable the button despite what the line edit contains

Comment: Then just connect the `QLineEdit::textChanged` signal to a custom slot of yours where you enable the button.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom slot where you enable your button. Connect `QLineEdit::textChanged` to this slot (if you have many line edits, connect them all):

*your class header:*

```
public slots:
    void textChanged();
```

*somewhere in your class:*

```
    ...
    connect(ui->lineEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), this, SLOT(textChanged()));
    ...

void MyClass::textChanged()
{
    ui->button->setEnabled(true);
}
```

You can also use the [`QLineEdit::textEdited`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qlineedit.html#textEdited) signal instead of `textChanged`, if you don't want your slot to trigger when the text is changed programatically.

EDIT: Here is the full example, you just need to add the line edit and push button in your MainWindow UI (I also disabled the button in the UI).

*mainwindow.h*

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QList>
#include <QLineEdit>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void textChanged();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QList<QLineEdit*> _editList;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

*mainwindow.cpp*

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->lineEdit1, SIGNAL(textEdited(QString)), this, SLOT(textChanged()));
    connect(ui->lineEdit2, SIGNAL(textEdited(QString)), this, SLOT(textChanged()));
    connect(ui->lineEdit3, SIGNAL(textEdited(QString)), this, SLOT(textChanged()));
    _editList.append(ui->lineEdit1);
    _editList.append(ui->lineEdit2);
    _editList.append(ui->lineEdit3);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::textChanged()
{
    int modified_count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < _editList.length(); i++)
    {
        if(!_editList[i]->text().isEmtpy)
            modified_count++;
    }
    if(modified_count >= 3)
        ui->pushButton->setEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: this does not function well

Comment: because the button is not enabled (true)

Comment: code at class.h: public slots: void enableButton();                   code at class.cpp: void ClassName::enableButton() {ui->pushButton->setEnabled(true);} and the connection part: connect(ui->lineEdit,SIGNAL(textEdited()),ui->pushButton,SLOT(enableButton));

Comment: @programingdelphi Well if you look at the application output window, you'll notice that you get a message like `No such signal QLineEdit::textEdited()`. The signal's signature is `QLineEdit::textEdited(const QString &text)`. Look at my example closely, and you'll notice that I have `QString` as a parameter type in there.

Comment: because this slot isn't connected with QPushButton

Comment: thanks a lot, now it works. The problem was that I didn't use "this". Another issue: I want the button to enable after some line edits have been filled not only one. What should I do?

Comment: @programingdelphi Connect every line edit you have to the same slot.

Comment: but only after three line edits have been filled, the button should become enabled.

Comment: @programingdelphi modified my answer. Basically you just add your line edits to a `QList` container, and in the slot, iterate through it and check how many have been modified.